# Socket concurrency in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, concurrency, amphp

I would like to know if anyone has any good insight into how to open a number of sockets to the same server, write and then read data concurrently in PHP. Should I use a concurrency framework like Amphp or are there better options for this task? How would I go ahead and build this?
Basically I want to achieve something like this in a nonblocking manner:

```
foreach ($conns as $c) {
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $c['host'], $c['port']);
    socket_write($socket, $c['message'], strlen($c['message']));
    $result = socket_read ($socket, 1024);
    socket_close($socket);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You write and read data sequentially in loop. Try to made two loops - in firest write and then in second read and names value of sockets in array:

```
$socket[] = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$result = socket_connect(current($socket), $c['host'], $c['port']);
socket_write(current($socket), $c['message'], strlen($c['message']));
```

In second loop read them and close:

```
foreach ($socket as $sc) {
    $result = socket_read ($sc, 1024);
    socket_close($sc);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did try something similar, but I keep getting `unable to connect: Transport endpoint is already connected` on the second iteration of create. Am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: how muh connections you required? Try to set value $backlog differ from 0 - socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 128);

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'll need 10 connections. `socket_create` doesn't support 128 as protocol (3rd parameter).
Right now my problem with the above seem to be that resource is not available when I read from the socket. I get `Resource temporarily unavailable`.